# SORM: Mapping fields to custom column names?

Tags: sorm

From the SORM documentation, it's not really clear and the API does not help.

So, how do I specify a custom column name in an entity? I would also like to change the column name of the primary key for each entity. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Changing column names isn't possible because SORM is all about convention over configuration. That's what makes it simple.

The primary key isn't configurable either, but [for different reasons](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#persisted_trait_and_ids).

Comment: Frankly, that's a blocker for me. As many others I am coming to SORM from a different ORM and I already have a deployed and used schema which I don't really want to change (for some it might not even be an option, if the schema is also used by other apps). Middleware comes and goes, data stays forever. So middleware should fit the schema, not the other way!

Comment: @SkyDan The general approach is: instead of customizing SORM, customize your database to fit it. If it's not an option, than unfortunately SORM is not an option for you. That's just a way it goes. Anyway, because of how involved the mapping of types behind SORM actually is (e.g., Tuples span several columns, Seq requires intermediate tables and etc.) chances are just making the column names customizable wouldn't have solved your issue, but surely would have opened dozens of others.